# Send video stream by bluetooth on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, bluetooth

I have a device with a camera and i want to connect to it using my iPhone via Bluetooth, so the question: is it possible to send real-time video stream by bluetooth using Swift/Objective - C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The transmission speed of Bluetooth is not strong enough to stream a video in real-time to another device. If it was audio it is potentially a different story.

You can use bluetooth to transfer a video to another device, but not to stream as far as I know.

Comment: So maybe it is possible to send video stream using wi-fi connection between iPhone and some kind of camera. Are there any libraries that can provide that kind of connection?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess you should look at the MultipeerConnectivity framework from Apple.